# Regular expression to remove anything but alphanumeric & spaces (in PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove, via regular expression, all but alphanumeric characters & spaces.

Here's the conversion I am hoping to achieve.

```
"I am a string" → "I am a string"
"How are you?" → "How are you"
"#53-Jeff" → "53-Jeff"
```

So far I have this:

```
return preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/","", $val);
```

But being a regex novice, I can't figure out how to insert a space. I had odd results when I tried.

Comment: `"#53-Jeff"->"53-Jeff"` Hyphen is not an alphanumeric character or a space.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inserting a space is just as simple as you expect it to be:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/", "", $val);
```

Btw. your third example is not clear to me: Do you want to replace the `-` too? If not, you need to add it to the character list too.

See [this](http://codepad.org/06oWrSQa) for a running example.

Comment: oh ignore the - thing. It's that simple? I was looking up symbols for spaces. dear lord.

Comment: Yeah, basically the square brackets are character sequences for regular expressions. They match any character that is specified inside, unless it’s prefixed with `^` which turns the meaning around. So you match any characters except the ones you specified. The `-` between two values is just a shortcut for common ranges; so `[0-9]` is basically identical to `[0123456789]`.

Comment: I'm learning lots about regex syntaxes these days, thank you so much for your insightful explanation. Coming from a PHP/javascript/jQuery background (and tonnes of visual design on Adobe PS and IL) this is a very new way to think & reason in my brain - a different approach for sure, so challenging. But made easier by kind folks like you. I hope to pass on the good deed one day when I become better at this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z -]/", "", $val);
```

Keep in mind to add the "-" to the very end of the character set block, or it might get interpreted as a range operator.

Depending on your regex flags (if whitespace/comments are enabled) you might need to replace the `" "` (right before the `"-"`) with a `"\s"` or (stricter) `"\ "`.

Comment: `\s` matches more than just spaces, it matches any whitespace character, so it’s not the same. Also regexp flags shouldn’t change the behaviour within character classes.

Comment: This highly depends on the regex engine being used. (ICU for example ignores whitespace if given flag is set, even in character sets, requiring `"\ "`)

Comment: Interesting, but I don’t think this is an issue with PHP’s PCRE. The `x` (PCRE_EXTENDED) flag won’t ignore whitespace within character classes.

Comment: Not in PCRE, but found it worth mentioning nevertheless, as it's worth knowing about those pitfalls. Not all Regexes are created equal. The mentioned issue with ICU once stole me about an hour of my life. I'd have never expected it to allow ignored whitespace within char sets. Probably a bug, not an implementation detail.

Comment: PCRE & ICU chats are way over my head, but thank you for your input nonetheless.