# Remove all alphanumeric characters except spaces?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to remove anything but alphanumeric & spaces (in PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107815/regular-expression-to-remove-anything-but-alphanumeric-spaces-in-php)

I'm trying to get

```
//before preg_replace -> Hi (Jimmy),

$string = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $string);

//after current preg_replace -> HiJimmy
//what it should be -> Hi Jimmy
```

preg_replace removing all alphanumeric characters, except for spaces. Is this possible?

Comment: sorry about the duplicate, I should have searched more. Voted to close

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add a space to your group:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\da-z ]/i', '', $string);
//                              ^ Notice the space here
```

Comment: You could add, for completeness, that spaces are not anything special in a regex, except if you use `/x`.